# Is it profitable to mine Bitcoin on iPhone X?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, mining-reward

I'm a newbie to mining, so in just trying to explore our. I wish to know if it's profitable to mint it on iPhone X?

What I mean by profitability is making between $1000 - $3000 monthly by mining. This should be the worth is the Bitcoin mined daily.
.
I've installed Mobile miner. Please, experts, I need your contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not profitable.

Mining Bitcoin on anything except specialized ASIC machines is pointless, and you will never see any returns, especially with a phone.

Even with ASICs, profits in the range of 1000-3000 would require tens of thousands of up front investment, access to cheap power, and storage space for the machines.